# Can't delete Safari history entry on Mac!

Tags: mac, safari, browser-history

MacBook pro 2014, OSX El Capitan 10.11.6
There're two history entries that I can't delete (as seen in pics). Whether I chose to clear history of all time or manually delete entries, it just won't work. At first there's only a Feb 8 history entry stuck there which I didn't pay much attention but yesterday another Feb 28 shows up and really annoys me. I googled for a while but can't get any clue. I'm reluctant to resort to resetting because of data loss(saved passwords .etc). Please help!
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some googling I figured it out:

1. quit Safari;
2. open terminal and type:

   `cd ~/Library/Safari`

   `rm History.db History.db-lock`
3. open Safari again and they're gone.